# How to export all my pins and boards from Pinterest?

Tags: pinterest

Pinterest does not provide a proper export feature. How can I export all my pins and boards from Pinterest, in order to move to another bookmark manager such as [Raindrop.io](https://raindrop.io/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

I forked the Pinback tool and made the changes I describe below, so you can simply use [my fork](https://github.com/brettdonald/pinback) and it should work immediately.

### Original Post

[Raindrop advises](https://help.raindrop.io/import/) that those wanting to migrate from Pinterest should use the [Pinback](https://pinbackit.github.io/) [tool](https://github.com/pinbackit/pinback), and my searching was unable to locate any other option.

However, when I tried to use Pinback to export my pins, I received the following message, even though I was on my profile page:

> Log in and visit your profile (pinterest.com/username) or board to
> start.

Looking through the [code](https://github.com/pinbackit/pinback/blob/master/pinback.js), I discovered that it contains a regular expression to extract your username from the web address. That regular expression would have worked if I was using **pinterest.com**, but it did not work because my account is on **pinterest.com.au**. The way I got it to work was to:

- right-click the bookmarklet on my bookmarks bar and select Edit
- copy the code into a text editor
- locate the URL-encoded regular expression near the beginning

  - `%2F%5Ehttps%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.pinterest.%5Ba-z.%5D%7B2%2C5%7D%5C%2F%28%5Ba-z0-9_%5D%7B1%2C30%7D%29%2Fi`
- [decode](https://www.urldecoder.org/) it

  - `/^https:\/\/www.pinterest.[a-z.]{2,5}\/([a-z0-9_]{1,30})/i`
- [modify](https://regex101.com/r/GDUsNP/1) it for more relaxed matching

  - `/^https:\/\/www\.pinterest\..*?\/([a-z0-9_]{1,30})/i`
- [encode](https://www.urlencoder.org/) it

  - `%2F%5Ehttps%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww%5C.pinterest%5C..%2A%3F%5C%2F%28%5Ba-z0-9_%5D%7B1%2C30%7D%29%2Fi`
- replace the relevant section of the code in the text editor
- copy the new code back to my browser as the new code for the bookmarklet

After I made these changes the bookmarklet worked properly, generating a downloadable HTML file containing all my pins, arranged into groups representing my boards. I was able to import this file straight into Raindrop.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can request a copy of your data from Pinterest https://help.pinterest.com/en/article/download-your-pinterest-data

1. Go to settings https://www.pinterest.com/settings
2. Go to "Privacy and data" https://www.pinterest.com/settings/privacy
3. In the "Request your data" section, click "Start request"
4. They will send you a link to the file with your exported data

By the looks of the exported html, it looks that you get a list of boards and a list of pins, but no information about which pin belongs to which board.

Comment: *no information about which pin belongs to which board*, which makes it completely and totally useless.